# How do I solve this optimization / geometry problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> A long, flat piece of sheet metal, 12" wide, is to be bent to form a long trough with cross sections an isosceles trapezoid. Find the shape of the trough with maximum cross-sectional area.

Here is an accompanying diagram:
[image]

First, observe that, having chosen $b$ and $\alpha$, the rest of the shape is completely determined, since we know that the sides must sum to $M = 12$. The side-length of the top side is equal to $M - a - 2b$, and so using the formula for the area of a trapezoid, we get that the area is:
$$A(b, \alpha) = \frac{1}{2}(M - 2b)b \sin(\alpha).$$
We seek $0 < b < \frac{M}{2}$ and $0 < \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ which maximize $A(b, \alpha)$. I compute the gradient of $A$:
$$\nabla A(b, \alpha) = \left(\frac{1}{2}(M - 2b)\sin(\alpha), \frac{1}{2}(M - 2b)b \cos(\alpha)\right)^T.$$
Now let's find the critical points of $A$ by solving $\nabla A = 0$. This leads to the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(M - 2b)\sin(\alpha) = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}(M - 2b)b \cos(\alpha) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation implies that $b = \frac{M}{2}$ (which is not even possible here.)

The answer in the back of the book (Multivariable Mathematics by Shifrin) is

> Bend up 4" on either side at an angle of $pi/3$.

So I must have done something wrong here. Could someone please help me figure out my mistake?

Comment: The trough is does not have a fourth side, covering the top.

Comment: @SammyBlack Oh, I should have looked up the meaning of "trough"; I thought it was a closed shape. How would I solve this problem if there is a fourth side?

Comment: The derivative w.r.t. b should be $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(M-4b)b \sin(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Sammy, you don't need the covering top. Therefore $M=a+2b.$ The formula for the area $A=A(a,b,\alpha)$ of a trapezoid reads:

$$A(a,b,\alpha)=\frac{a+(a+2\cdot \cos(\alpha))}{2}\cdot \sin(\alpha)\cdot b \left(=\frac{"short side"+"long side"}{2}\cdot "height"\right)$$

And so we´re minimizing:

$$\min_{a, b, \alpha} A(a,b,\alpha),\quad \text{s.t. } M=a+2b$$

$A$ is continuous and $C=[0, 12]\times [0, 12]\times [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ is compact, hence $A$ attains a maximum on $C$.
Define the Lagrangian by $L(a,b,\alpha, \lambda)=A(a,b,\alpha)+\lambda \cdot (M-a-2\cdot b).$ Then the KKT conditions read:

$$
0=\sin(\alpha)\cdot b-\lambda  \qquad  (1)\\
0=a\cdot \sin(\alpha)+2\cdot b \cdot \cos(\alpha)\cdot \sin(\alpha)-2\cdot \lambda \qquad (2)\\
0=ab\cdot \cos(\alpha)+b^2\cos(2\alpha)  \quad (3)\\
M=a+2b \quad (4)
$$ where $(1)-(3)$ is simply $\nabla_{(a,b,\alpha)}L=0$ and $(4)$ the equality constraint. Note that the system is uniquely solvable with solution $(a^*,b^ *,\alpha^*, \lambda^*)=(4,4,\pi/3, 2\sqrt{3}).$ $(a^*,b^*,\alpha^*)\in C$ hence it is a maximizer of $A$ as claimed in the text book.

$\textbf{For completeness:}$
Inserting $(1)$ into $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields:

$$
a\cdot \sin(\alpha)+b\sin(2\alpha)=2b\sin(\alpha) \quad (2')\\
a\cos(\alpha)+b\cos(2\alpha)=0 \quad (3')\\
$$

Since $\pi>\alpha\geq 0$ and $\alpha=0$ cannot be a maximizer, $(2')$ can be written as $a-2b+2b\cos(\alpha)=0$ after using the identity $\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cdot \cos(\alpha).$ Hence $$a=2b(1-\cos(\alpha)) \quad (5).$$
Now $(4)$ yields with $M=12$ $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{2b-6}{b} \quad (6).$$
Using $\cos(2\alpha)=-1+2\cos^2(\alpha)$ and inserting $(5),(6)$ into $(3)$ yields :

$$
2b(\frac{b-2b+6}{b})\cdot(\frac{2b-6}{b})+b(-1+2(\frac{2b-6}{b})^2)=0
$$ and this is solved for $[b^*=4][1].$ Using $(6)$ and $(5)$, we obtain $\alpha^*=\frac{\pi}{4}, a^*=4$.

Comment: I did the problem using gradients but I got the same angle as given in the question, $\alpha=\pi/3$. I have not checked your solution carefully, but an error which I made when I did this was to forget factors of 2 when doing things like $2\sin\cos=\sin2$ or when differentiating $\sin2$, and the first time I did the problem I got $\alpha=\pi/4$, so that might be the origin of the discrepancy. If my solution is wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution was given in the comments, but I'm just bunging the answer here since I did the problem out of interest.

For the area,
$$
A=\frac12(\text{top}+\text{bottom})\times \text{height}
$$
so given $a=12-2b$, height$=b\sin\alpha$, etc., I got
$$
A=b\sin\alpha(12-2b+b\cos\alpha)
$$
The partial derivative
$$
{\partial A\over\partial b}=12\sin\alpha+2b(\cos\alpha-2)\sin\alpha=0
$$
gives
$$
b={6\over 2-\cos\alpha}
\tag{1}
$$
at the maximum, and
$$
{\partial A\over\partial \alpha}=12b\cos\alpha+b^2\cos2\alpha-2b^2\cos\alpha=0
\tag{2}
$$
This looks like a mess, but dividing out one of the $b$ factors, substituting (1) into (2), and using $\cos2\alpha=2\cos^2-1$, it easily simplifies down to $\cos\alpha=\frac12$. From physical considerations we see that $\alpha=\pi/3$, and substituting $\cos\alpha=1/2$ into (1) gives $b=4$.